# Only keeping string text present in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, text, subset

I am relatively new in R.

I have two dataframes, each of one variable only called `final` and `cv`.

`final` looks like:

```
V1
humans, aged, female, stroke
infant, male, echocardiography
aneurysm, adolescent, female, diabetes
pregnant, diabetes, female
cardiovascular diseases, complications
```

and `cv` looks like

```
V2
stroke
pregnant
echocardiography
aneurysm
diabetes
cardiovascular diseases
```

I want to manipulate `final` so that it only includes the text present in `cv`. This is what I want the resulting dataframe of `final` to look like:

```
V1
stroke
echocardiography
aneurysm, diabetes
pregnant, diabetes
cardiovascular diseases
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Do not copy/paste your data here. Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `stringr`. In addition, the `or1` function from `rebus` is very useful to construct regular expression phrases. `str_extract_all` can extract all the matched string. If there are more than one phrases, the output of `str_extract_all` will create something like `c("aneurysm", "diabetes")`. I used several `str_replace` call with `fixed` to replace `c(`, `)`, and `"` to nothing. This part can be done more efficiently using regex, but I am not familiar with regex. `df_final` is the final output.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

# Create example data frame
df1 <- data_frame(V1 = c("humans, aged, female, stroke", "infant, male, echocardiography",
                         "aneurysm, adolescent, female, diabetes", "pregnant, diabetes, female",
                         "cardiovascular diseases, complications"))
df2 <- data_frame(V2 = c("stroke", "pregnant", "echocardiography", "aneurysm", 
                         "diabetes", "cardiovascular diseases"))

# Process the data
df_final <- df1 %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_extract_all(V1, or1(df2$V2))) %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_replace(V1, fixed("c("), "")) %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_replace(V1, fixed(")"), "")) %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_replace_all(V1, fixed('"'), ""))
```

Comment: thanks, but your code only extracted the first phrase that shows up in each row. for instance, in the third row, I want both `aneurysm, diabetes` but your code only outputs `aneurysm`

Comment: @sweetmusicality Please see my updates. I believe `df_final` matches your  expected output now.

Comment: thanks - I will try this. could you update your variables however so that both dataframes have different variables (`V1` and `V2`) because I'm afraid that I will use the wrong variables otherwise. thanks!

Comment: Based on the update from your original update, I have also updated my code accordingly.

Comment: how would I go about string matching if `final$V1` doesn't have phrases separated by commas (no separation at all - and still need exact match from `cv$V2`?

Comment: @sweetmusicality You may want to ask a new question.

Comment: I have, but no one is answering it, yikes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592850/finding-all-string-matches-from-another-dataframe-in-r